# What would be the best choice for integrating a real-time connection in flask API?

Tags: python, flask

Currently we have developed an API using Flask that works in a traditional request-response style (client is a mobile application). This API is hosted using Apache on the remote server. What we would like to do is integrate the real-time connections between server and client (just like a chat app). This is where I got stuck. I need to make choice for the framework here. Using Tornado with Flask will not be a good choice since Tornado is non-blocking but Flask is blocking. What would be the best choice in this case?

Comment: Maybe wrong idea but `"write your own !"`, you think real-time, which is best and fast of course `socket`. Never a python `network-module` faster than `socket` !

Comment: You mean, I should use `socket`? And should write one from scratch? Pardon me, I couldn't understand your comment properly.

Comment: Yes, write new ! Most application info say : `minimal,faster,secure`, why `minimal` is important ? some times we make wrong choice, like : `buy a  mainboard for fast RAM(DDR3)` but never faster than `SDRAM`, what is `technology` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think today's default solution to provide realtime capabilities for web applications are websockets (Please google Flask+websockets). If concurrency is an issue (i.e. many long-lasting, simultaneous connections), the "chain" of software handling the websockets should be non-blocking (otherwise many threads will eat up your resources while doing nothing). You can continue to use flask, as it supports gevent (a non-blocking monkey-patch for the Python stdlib), but your are probably better off with nginx than Apache as the reverse proxy since it has always been non-blocking. For example, nginx+gevent+flask would provide you a nonblocking setup.

Personally, I like Tornado a lot, but I would be reluctant to introduce another framework into your application if you already went a long way with Flask.

Comment: Would using `Celery` be a good idea here? What i mean is, I can have an endpoint exposed for connections and on each request call a `Celery` task. For example, if I want to send a message, I could have a task for that and use push notifications to get the message delivered?

Comment: Celery is an asynchronous task processor that usually runs outside your web application. So it depends on your kind of realtime use case (e.g. regarding concurrency, IO bandwidth and CPU throughput) if it makes sense to employ a separate task processsor.